# Macro not expanded with direct call, but expanded with indirect

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

I've got the following macros

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define DB_FIELD(...) BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)

#define DB_TOFIELD(type,name) \
  private:\
  type name##_;\
  public:\
  const type& get_##name(){return name##_;}\
  void set_##name(const type& val) { name##_ = val; }

#define GEN_ENUM_FIELD(r,data,elem) BOOST_PP_CAT(FIELD_,BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1,elem)),

#define DECLARE(type, name) DB_TOFIELD(type, name)

#define GEN_FIELD_DECL(r, data, elem) DECLARE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,elem),BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1,elem))

#define DB_TABLE(name, ...) class name : public DataBaseTable {\
  public:\
  constexpr static const char *get_table_name() { return #name; }\
  BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(GEN_FIELD_DECL,, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_LIST(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  enum Fields{ \
  BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(GEN_ENUM_FIELD,, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_LIST(__VA_ARGS__))\
  FIELD_COUNT\
  };\
  };
```

Now the following code:

```
DB_TABLE(Test2,
  DB_FIELD(int, foo),
  DB_FIELD(int, bar)
)
```

Generates:

```
class Test2 : public DataBaseTable {
public:
  constexpr static const char *get_table_name() { return "Test2"; }
private:
  int foo_;
public:
  const int &get_foo() { return foo_; }
  void set_foo(const int &val) { foo_ = val; }
private:
  int bar_;
public:
  const int &get_bar() { return bar_; }
  void set_bar(const int &val) { bar_ = val; }
  enum Fields { FIELD_foo, FIELD_bar, FIELD_COUNT };
};
```

Which is as ugly as I wrote it, but my concern is **why do I need this level of indirection (*DECLARE*) in the GEN_FIELD_DECL macro** ? The direct call to **DB_TOFIELD**

```
#define GEN_FIELD_DECL(r, data, elem) DB_TOFIELD(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,elem),BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1,elem))
```

produces garbage:

```
class Test2 : public DataBaseTable {
public:
  constexpr static const char *get_table_name() { return "Test2"; }
private:
  int foo _;
public:
  const int &get_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, (int)(foo))() { return foo _; }
  void set_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, (int)(foo))(const int &val) { foo _ = val; }
private:
  int bar _;
public:
  const int &get_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, (int)(bar))() { return bar _; }
  void set_BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, (int)(bar))(const int &val) { bar _ = val; }
  enum Fields { FIELD_foo, FIELD_bar, FIELD_COUNT };
};
```

The same behavior is reproduced with clang 3.7.1 and gcc 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are running into is an exception to how the preprocessor expands parameters if they are arguments to the `#` or `##` operators. From C++.2011 §16.3.1¶1:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution
>   takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, ***unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or
>   followed by a `##` preprocessing token*** (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros
>   contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens
>   are available.

The macro indirection avoids the exception clause, causing the argument to be expanded before being processed by the other macro.

For example:

```
#define FOO 10
#define BAR(x) x ## 7
#define BAR2(x) BAR(x)

int x = BAR(FOO);      // => int x = FOO7;

int y = BAR2(FOO);     // => int y = BAR(10); (intermediate result)
                       // => int y = 107;     (final expansion)
```